# Tab key is not working properly in group box

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net

i am using controls (textbox, combobox, checkbox, etc) with Groupbox and without groupbox in the form

Tab function key is not going to the Groupbox Controls

For Example

```
Form1
{
Textbox1
Textbox2
Combobox1


Groupbox (In the Form1 Itself)
{
Textbox3
Checkbox
}


Save (Button)
}
```

Once form1 loaded, textbox1 will be focus, then i click the tab it's going to textbox2, combobox1 and save button.  The Tab is not going to Group box (textbox3, checkbox)

How to solve this problem.

Need VB.Net Code Help....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the form is a vb.net form then you can use the tab order option.

Just make sure that you have layout toolbar available (View >> toolbars >> layout) then select the tab order control and click through the controls in the order you want the tab to work. That way you can visualise the tab order of the form.

I would upload a screen shot to show you where the option is but as I am new on here I am prevented from doing so however it is the last icon on the layout toolbar.

I hope this is useful

Answer (score 1):

It should not be the case. It should work fine. Make sure Controls in the groupbox have their TabStop property set to true. Select your form and View->Tab Order may also help. If groupbox have its TabIndex to "X" then its child controls will have tabindex as "X.0",  "X.1" and so on. But in general tab do stop at groupboxes. Try changing the TabIndex of groupbox may also solve the problem. And I don't see any need to write any code for it. Property window is more than enough to solve these kind of issues.

Hope it helps.